# Storing Google Analytics Client ID in Shopify with every order

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

The goal here is to be able to tie all Shopify orders (including cases where Javascript tracking fails) back to an anonymous Google Analytics user.

The way to solve this is to collect Google Analytics Client ID with every order stored in Shopify. I believe this is doable with [order level metafields](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield?api[version]=2020-04). Although, I'm not sure what is the best way to set this metafield and make sure it gets added even if the order is completed on a third-party service provider site (i.e. Paypal, Amazon).

PS! The Client ID can be set before the order is actually finalized since it's possible to filter using order status later on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Answer (score 0):

I have used TransactionID in google Analytics to tie an order in GA with Shopify where this field is called OrderID. After that, it is easy to identify the customer and then troll through Shopify and see their lifetime value. This becomes particularly interesting when you want to see the transition of different traffic sources for each order by shoppers.